# I have a small code on the end of each image link on my site that I didn't add. Does anybody know what this is?

Tags: security

mywebsiteurl.net/image.jpg?9a7ad6

What is this "?9a7ad6" after each image link? I noticed this when I copy pasted the url of an image.

I googled it, but the only relevant thing that I could find is that #9a7ad6 is the hex code for purple.

Comment: is it always the same code ? could we have a look at it online ?

Comment: Is this always image.jpg or file names differ?

Comment: What is your webserver?  It could be adding a query string to prevent caching when the image changes.

Comment: Is it a dynamically generated image?

Comment: It's always the same code that I pasted here. It is on all the images that I have on the site. To give a little extra info about it, the site is a Wordpress blog that has the W3 total cache plugin and Cloudflare also. The curious thing about this is that I have the same W3 Total cache + cloudflare configuration on other sites too and this is the only one where I get the code.

Answer (score 0):

Some WordPress themes/plugins use query strings to do neat things to images on the fly like resizing.  In this case, the query string (stuff after the ?) is likely being used to prevent caching.  If that is the case, here's how to fix it:

> There's a setting under Browser Cache → General that says Prevent
>   caching of objects after settings change → Whenever settings are
>   changed, a new query string will be generated and appended to objects
>   allowing the new policy to be applied. Disable that (if you're using
>   the plugin) and those query strings will be dropped on static
>   resources like .jpg and .png files.

Source:  Philip Arthur Moore from WordPress.org:  http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-32-images-show-weird-query-string

You may also want to take a look at this page:  http://diywpblog.com/wordpress-optimization-remove-query-strings-from-static-resources/